# Have I shown it correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, holomorphic-functions

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and let $$f(x,z):X\times G\to \mathbb{C}$$ is holomorphic for each fixed $x\in X$. I want to show that $$\frac{1}{h}(f(x,z_0+h)-f(x,z_0))=\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,z_0+ht)dt, \quad 0<|h|<r,\, x\in X$$

$$h\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,z_0+ht)dt=\int_0^1f'(x,z_0+ht)hdt=\int_\gamma f'(x,w)dw=f(x,z_0+h)-f(x,z_0)$$
where $\gamma=z_0+ht \quad t\in [0,1]$

Comment: You haven't used the assumption that $|h|<r$, so that should indicate that something hasn't been fleshed out or your reasoning isn't quite correct.

Comment: @user23793 I sorry, i forgot to mentioned we looked the the ball $B(z_0,r)$ contained in $G$.

Comment: Ah, good. Can you justify the last step? Why can we use the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals?

Comment: @user23793 Because $z_0$ and $z_0+h$ are both contained in $G$, and because $f'$ is a continuous function with a primitive $f$, we can use the fund. theorem to evalute the integral along any path between the two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $r$ is important because to be holomorphic is a local property, so we want to be inside $G$ when we're working with continuity and derivatives of $f$. Fix $(x,z_0)\in X\times G$, with $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ open. Then we may find $r$ such that $z_0+h\in G$ with $0<|h|<r$. When you write $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,z_0+ht)$, I think you really mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,z(t))$, where $z(t)=z_0+ht$. In this case we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}f(x,z(t))dt=f(x,z(1))-f(x,z(0))=f(x,z_0+h)-f(x,z_0).
\end{align*}
However, $\frac{d}{dt}f(x,z(t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,z(t))\frac{dz}{dt}=h\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,z(t))$. Thus, 
\begin{align*}
f(x,z_0+h)-f(x,z_0)=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}f(x,z(t))dt=h\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,z(t))dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated.